# Limit of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mu:\mathcal{A}\to [0,\infty]$ be a measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ over $X$ and let $(A_n)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$.

I want to show that when $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ holds for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)$.

So we have to show convergence of this sequence.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Else there is nothing to show, as both sides just equal $\infty$.

Let now $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. I want to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\geq N$ we have that

$|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\right)-\mu(A_n)|<\varepsilon$.

As $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1}$ we have that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i=A_n$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now I "disjointinize" (is there a term for that?), the $A_n$, by setting

$B_0=\emptyset$, $B_1= A_1\setminus B_0$ and $B_n=A_n\setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1} B_i$.

Then the $B_i$ are pairwise disjoint and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$.

Using this and the $\sigma$-additivity of the measure, we get:

$|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\right)-\mu(A_N)|=|\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n\right)-\mu(B_N)|=\dotso =\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \mu(B_n)$

Where as $N\to\infty$ we get $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \mu(B_n)\to 0$.

So for every $\varepsilon >0$ we find such an desired $N$.

I am not satisfied by this argument, using $N\to\infty$ and stating that the series converges to $0$.

What do you think about this proof?
I am happy to read your comments on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ for all $n$ implies $\mu(\cup_{n\geq 1} A_n)<\infty$? Also, you need not resort to the $\epsilon$-N argument. Rather, using your notation and using the $\sigma$-additivity, we have $$\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}A_n\biggr)=\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n\geq 1}B_n\biggr)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\mu(B_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(B_n)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\mu\biggl(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}B_n\biggr)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\mu(A_N).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee As far as I can tell, I have never stated (or used) that $\mu(\bigcup A_n)<\infty$. Ah, I see. Your calculation makes it much smoother. Thanks for that.

Comment: The $\epsilon$-$N$ argument will work only when the limit is finite. For example, if $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\mu=\operatorname{Leb}$, and $A_n=[0,n]$, then $\mu(A_n)=n<\infty$ for all $n$ but $\mu(\cup_n A_n)-\mu(A_N) = \infty$ for any $N$.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what is going wrong, and what you pointed out. I see the flaw now. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, and glad it helped :)

Comment: Keep up the good work!